# Exception caught by widgets library. Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, expand

I am getting this error. I read that with this error the problem is `Expanded` and solution to use it with a `column`, `row` or `flex`. But in my code, I use it that way, so there should be no error. Please help me.

My code:

```
  List<DataColumn> initHeader() {
    List<DataColumn> header = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < widget.headerList.length; i++) {
      header.add(new DataColumn(
          label: Flexible(
        child: Text(
          widget.headerList[i].name,
        ),
      )));
    }
    return header;
  }
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: can you share `tableReport()` widget, i belive it is coming from there

Comment: Can you show the error?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh and John Oyekanmi I edited my question

Comment: and about `HeaderTable`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I again edited my question. There is everything now.

Comment: are you using any pub package for this `HeaderTable`? and can you add an that you are trying to archive

Comment: No, I just import the components whose code I added to the question (`headerTable`, `orderDetailSimpleTable` and `simpleTable`)

Comment: well i cant find `HeaderTable` there, can you recheck the question

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I edited my question in "my code" at the beginning of my question . I added more details to this. Sorry that there is so much code, but I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: my ui is building without any errors on terminal,it seems you arenot using  null-safety, 2nd can you provide image that you like to archive , or git repo that can be workOn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `Flexible` to `Container` and it works good without error.

Before:

```
  List<DataColumn> initHeader() {
    List<DataColumn> header = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < widget.headerList.length; i++) {
      header.add(new DataColumn(
          label: Flexible(
        child: Text(
          widget.headerList[i].name,
        ),
      )));
    }
    return header;
  }
```

After:

```
  List<DataColumn> initHeader() {
    List<DataColumn> header = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < widget.headerList.length; i++) {
      header.add(new DataColumn(
          label: Container(
        child: Text(
          widget.headerList[i].name,
        ),
      )));
    }
    return header;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

lets use this code its will solve your peoblem

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
         body: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
           //ontroller: skuController,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
          //labelText: AppLocalizations.instance.text('Scan'),
        suffixIcon: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(Icons.search),
        ),
        ),
      ),
     //ableReport(this.getProduct()),
      Row(
      children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
      child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
      child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('Submit'),
      ),
      )),
      Expanded(
      child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
      child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text(
      'Check items',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      ),
      )),
      ],
      ),
      ],
      ),
      ));
    }
    }
```